# Python - file lines - pallindrome

Tags: python, python-2.7, palindrome

I have been doing python tasks for learning and I came across this task where I have to read a file that includes few words and if a line is palindrome (same when written backwards: lol > lol)
so I tried with this code but It doesn't print anything on the terminal:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == line[::-1]:
            print line
```

But if I print like this, without an if condition, it prints the words:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

I wonder why It wont print the words that I've written in the file:

```
sefes
kurwa
rawuk
lol
bollob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because those lines contain `"\n"` on the end. `"\n"` means new line. Therefore none of those are palindromes according to python.

You can strip off the `"\n"` first by doing:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == line.strip()[::-1]:
            print line
```

Comment: @matt @farhan-k  Thank you alot :D This worked `if line.strip() == line[::-1].strip():`

Comment: @Idontreallywolf Yeah that's fine too. `strip()` strips whitespace from the beginning and end so it doesn't matter where you put the ``.strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

The last character of each `line` is a newline character ("\n"). You need to strip trailing newlines (`"foo\n".strip()`) before checking whether the line is a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

When you read a line from a file like this, you also get the newline character. So, e.g., you're seeing `'sefes\n'`, which when reversed is `'\nsefes'`. These two lines are of course not equal. One way to solve this is to use `rstrip` to remove these newlines:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line == line[::-1]:
            print line
```